# How can I use `active` column with relationship?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

### Parents model

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    children = db.relationship(Child, backref='parents')
```

### Children model

```
class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Parent.id))
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
```

Assuming `Parent` and `Child` model has 1:N relationship (Apparently in above) I want to get only `activated` column according to `is_active` value.

Is there any trick that does not require an additional filter for querying only activated child rows?

For example,

Let's assume `Child` table has rows as below:

[image]

And the query would be like:

```
p = Parent.query.filter(**some_conditions).one()
p.children  # Then the second row (id=2, is_active=False) shouldn't be here
```

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I've had to modify your models a tiny bit to make them into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The example below is very similar to the one given in the official docs here: [Specifying Alternate Join Conditions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions), but the key point is that:

> The default behavior of relationship() when constructing a join is that it equates the value of primary key columns on one side to that of foreign-key-referring columns on the other. **We can change this criterion to be anything we’d like using the primaryjoin argument**...

So following with your example, by default, SQLAlchemy will join the relationship by following the foreign key path between Parent.id and Child.parent_id. However, you can make this join condition to be practically anything you want. E.g.:

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship("Child", backref='parents')
    active_children = db.relationship("Child",
        primaryjoin="and_(Parent.id == Child.parent_id, "
                    "Child.is_active==True)")
```

As you can see, our `primaryjoin` argument now is the string representation of an [`and_()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_) function call, where we ask the relationship to join both on the foreign key path between the two models, *and* on whether `Child.is_active` is `True`. At runtime, SQLAlchemy will evaluate the function to emit the SQL used to get the relevant rows from the database.

Here's my full code and a basic test:

```
import random

class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    children = db.relationship("Child", backref='parents')
    active_children = db.relationship("Child",
        primaryjoin="and_(Parent.id == Child.parent_id, "
                    "Child.is_active==True)")

class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Parent.id))
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    parent = Parent(id=1)
    db.session.add(parent)

    for _ in range(10):
        child = Child(parent_id=1, is_active=random.choice([True, False]))
        db.session.add(child)
    db.session.commit()

    print(parent.children)
    print(parent.active_children)
    assert all(c.is_active for c in parent.active_children)
```

One caveat is that you can still add `Child` instances to the `Parent.active_children` relationship attribute where `Child.is_active == False`, and they will be tracked by the session and made persistent upon commit. This only governs the results that are pulled from the database upon query.

Comment: When we add the primaryjoin `and_(Parent.id == Child.parent_id, Child.is_active==True)` can we omit the condition `Parent.id == Child.parent_id`? Is it override the original condition of `relationship`?

Comment: That's easy to test, just change the `primaryjoin` condition in my test code above to `"Child.is_active==True"` and see what happens.

Comment: What about m2m cases? Could you add an example code snippet?